# Background-attachment: fixed in ie10 causing image to jump

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

as said in title, I am having problems with `background-attachment:fixed` in internet explorer.

Here is an example of my problem:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKTkg/)

As you can see, it works nicely in all browsers accept IE. What I have noticed is that if you disable  smooth scrool, the jumping stops(Tools --> Internet options --> advance --> Browsing -->Smooth scrool), but the page does not look that nice. This is of coruse not a solution, because one can't explain to visitors to disable smooth scroll.

So...does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that Microsoft are working on. It's so bloody annoying